# PHP, AJAX, MYSQLI, Not inserting a row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to insert a row to the DB via ajax request, but the row is not inserting to the DB

```
 //Simple form
<div class="form_style">
<form action="#" method="POST">
<textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5" 
placeholder="Enter some text"></textarea>
<button id="FormSubmit">Add record</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And the response.php

```
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"])){
 //MYSQL CLASS
include('includes/mysql.inc.php');
file_get_contents('php://input');
 //Accessing the POST variables
$contentToSave = $_POST["content_txt"]; 
 //Inserting the row    
$insert_row = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES 
('".$contentToSave."')";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $insert_row);    
 }
else
{
//This block is executing right the moment, seems like $_POST datas not 
POSTING
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error occurred, Could not process request!');
exit();
} //seems like maybe the jquery include file is not proper? but i checked it connecting not locally to the jquery library
```

But the row is not inserting to the DB

Comment: So what's the actual error you get?

Comment: Debug your script in each stage and find the actual problem..

Comment: column name should not enclosed by single quotes .  "INSERT INTO comments ('comment') VALUES 
('".$contentToSave."')"

Comment: @AndyHolmes only page refreshes thats it

Comment: @JYoThI let my try

Comment: @JYoThI isn't worked

Comment: As you said your page refreshing . so that first of your ajax call not working .

Comment: @JYoThI it's working, headers from the response.php  set HTTP/1.1 500 error

Comment: data should be send properly like this  data:{content_txt:$("#contentText").val()},

Comment: @JYoThI not working as well, page refreshes

Comment: That's what i said before @Andrew

Comment: @JYoThI I set the data send properly, now the page is not refreshing but in response.php i have an empty set of the POST

Comment: put this code in response.php echo file_get_contents('php://input'); to know value is posting or not .

Comment: @JYoThI returns blank

Comment: can you update with your current code @Andrew

Comment: remove all the line in response.php put this single line echo file_get_contents('php://input'); and tell me the output @Andrew

Comment: @JYoThI a minute please

Comment: @JYoThI textarea just clears it's contents and that is it

Comment: on update you missed to update your ajax code to here

Comment: @JYoThI seems like found the solution, because of my htaccess rewriting the .php, in my ajax code i done the following url: "../response.php" to url: "../response", now there is no error, but no row inserted again

Comment: can you update with your current code @Andrew

Comment: @JYoThI i solved my problem lol))) the problem was that in my html template i had two <form> tags therefore the other browsers was not functioning

Answer (score 0):

In your insert statement,  remove the single quotes around the comment.  What you need is back ticks to properly escape if you are trying to access a MySQL reserved keyword

Comment: not worked at all, headers sent HTTP/1.1 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have quoted the column name. Use

```
$insert_row = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES 
('".$contentToSave."')";
```

Comment: not worked at all, headers sent HTTP/1.1 500 error

Comment: @Andrew, you need to give me some error responses. Regarding the query itself in my answer is not the problem.

Comment: While inserting the page refreshes, however it not has to refresh the page

Comment: @Andrew, that's a different question, let's focus on "not inserting row" in this question. If you have another problem you ask another question, that's how it works in Stackoverflow.